# UIPickerView 2 components values iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to use `UIPickerView` with 2 components, in which the second component value will be dependent on the first component value, like if in the first component Group 1 is selected then in the second component the group 1 values should be shown.

After selecting the values from both components value will be assigned to a `UITextField` or `UILabel` and the picker will be hidden.

(I have a main view in which I have added a subview to add the `UIPickerView`).

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
    if (component==0)
    {
        return [vGroup count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [vehiclePickerList count];
    }
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (component) 
    {
        case 0:
            return [vGroup objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case 1:
            return [vehiclePickerList objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: What is the question/what have you tried? (standard SO questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide some code what you have written. For component-related issues, use `- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView`.

Store corresponding values (which you want to show in component 2) of each row of component 1 in an array of dictionary, and load values from there.

Comment: unfortunately code has been deleted but this is the code from which I am trying to create the processes.

Comment: You did perfectly fine. Now, what is the problem you are facing ? If pickerView methods are not getting called, then add the delegate. If the data is not coming, add the datasource/check the vGroup and vehiclePickerList object/contents in log. For new item list in second component every time you click different first component row, change the contents of vehiclePickerList accordingly using - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component method.

Comment: thank you utsabiem :) but it wud be helpful if u tell me about the site from where I would get the code

Comment: Please don't hope to get ready-made code from anywhere. All the sites share only basic pickerview codes (I already gave a link). For other references, apple developer is best: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html. Please let us know what problem you are facing in the code snippet you yourself provided here. Then we may help/suggest accordingly.